# Integrate thunderbird in Gnome 15.10

Tags: gnome, 15.10, thunderbird, evolution

I'm using gnome shell. Many of the gnome apps (e.g. gnome contacts, the calender in the panel) use the evolution address book/calendar.. How can I tell them to use the data from thunderbird?

I tried evolution for a while, but while it works fine for contacts and calendar, it just is not reliable enough for emails. Is there any way to replace it with thunderbird?

Comment: Thunderbird does not have a native calendar... What exactly do you want to integrate?

Comment: But the add-on [Lightning](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/thunderbird/calendar) is now (since [TB 38.0.1](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/installing-lightning-thunderbird)) as default integrated.

Comment: There's still no addin to connect TB with the Gnome online accounts ...?

Answer (score -1):

I tried the following now:

```bash
# remove evolution packages
sudo apt-get remove evolution evolution-common evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common evolution-data-server-online-accounts

# install thunderbird
sudo apt-get install thunderbird tunderbird-common thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-local-en
```

I hope I did't miss anything.

Comment: I can't remove this packages without also removing gdm and gnome-shell...